# Java Spring Rest Call to get subclass using superclass

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, inheritance

I am trying to store multiple similar documents in the same document store (MongoDB) that is all classes that extend Foo are stored in the Foo Collection.

I have a rest endpoint called findById which returned a type of Optional e.g. /foo/{id}.

When I debug this, it is returning a class of Bar (which extends Foo

However, when I call this from a java Client Application.

Foo Class

```java
    @Data
    @Document(collection = "foo")
    public abstract class Foo {
        @Id
        private int id;

        public Foo(){}
        public Foo(int id){
            this.id = id;
        }
```

Bar Class

```java
    @Document(collection = "foo")
    @Data
    public class Bar extends Foo{
        private String text;

        @PersistenceConstructor
        public EnterValue(int id, String text){
            super(id);
            this.text = text;
        }

        @Override
        public int getId() {
            return super.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public int setId(UUID id) {
            super.setId(id);
        }

        public String getText(){
            return this.text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
```

Client Code:

```java
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<Foo> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/foo/123",HttpMethod.GET,entity,Foo.class);
```

I get a Error while extracting response for type [class Foo] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8].

Comment: please post the error and the controller too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the type you put inside ResponseEntity's diamond operator can't be abstract;
- it must implement Serializable.

`public class Bar extends Foo implements Serializable {
     ...
     }
     ...
     ResponseEntity<Bar> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/foo/123", HttpMethod.GET, entity, Bar.class);`

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this? I have somewhere else in the code a list objects that extend Foo with an Order. and As its being pulled from the DB I it could be any class that extends Foo.

Comment: I would make it ResponseEntity<String> to get raw body, and then later deserialize it into the type you want (using criteria you set).

ResponseEntity<Bar> just does exactly the same for you automagically, i.e. deserializes json string into Bar. 

Class that is not Serializable can't be deserialized; and abstract class can't be instantiated and thus can't be deserialized too.